# Admin panel slow response (5- 6 seconds)

Tags: magento-1.7

Generally the admin panel in my magento store is very responsieve 1-2 seconds. However sometimes the the response is much slower 5-6 seconds. I have reindexed, and refreshed and flushed cache, and still the same issue, 5-6 seconds response with every click.

I've been having this issue ON and OFF in the past, sometimes it would clear up and response will be back to 1-2 seconds.

p.s. Front end of site works very fast.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The front end of a Magento site has quite a bit of caching in place to keep things going as quickly as possible for the end user.  Add in a full page caching extension, too, and the overall load on the front end of the site can be extremely low.  That means that in order to serve the home page, the site doesn't have to hit the database to generate the page - it's all served out of a flat, static file.  In that case, the only time that an end user visiting the site will interact with the database is when they add something to their cart and then checkout.

With the Magento admin, there isn't as much caching available.  The sales order grid comes out of the Sales_flat_order_grid table; this is written to during the checkout process.  But it's still a database process that needs to run to generate that page.

Generally when there are bigger response times on an admin, there are background processes running (such as a reindex) or other memory intensive processes.  With solid caching, this shouldn't interfere with the front end of the site, but can make the checkout process go a bit more slowly.

So... a couple of options:

1. Just deal with it and know something is going on with the processes of the site, and it should be back fast again soon. (Less helpful.)
2. Upgrade your server with more memory and processing power so that intensive processes will not slow down the Magento admin.  Get as big of a system as you can afford, and ideally a ton of memory.
3. If you can, move the database to a different server that has enough memory to run the entire database in RAM if possible.
4. I might recommend installing a system like New Relic onto the server to see what is slowing down the site during these 5-6 second periods.  It may be a rogue extension or third party process that just wasn't designed well and can be better optimized.
5. Some of the larger sites we work on will have a separate admin server to access the Magento admin.  This can dramatically speed up things as well, but it's a more complex setup, of course.

I hope this helps!